# Is it possible to disable a specific key in OSX?

Tags: macos, keyboard, hardware

It appears my left shift key is permanently down on my MBP. All keys trigger capital letters, and numbers print out the symbols, I have to hold down `esc` when booting to prevent it from booting into safe mode...

I have taken the key off and cleaned underneath but that hasn't helped matters. If I open the visual keyboard I can see that the right shift responds to my presses but the left one does not, which leads me to think it is the one that is bust.

Is there any way for me to disable this key? I can make do with just using the right hand shift, obviously the laptop is practically un-usable with shift always being on...

Answer (score 4):

The only way I am aware of doing this is by using a program which used to be called KeyRemap4MacBook but is now called Karabiner.

Download here: https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/

If you would like a walk through, go here: https://www.quora.com/How-does-one-turn-off-their-shift-key-on-a-MacBook-Pro

Comment: You can't remap a stuck modifier key especially when it's affecting the system *before* it loads the OS

Comment: I needed to break my habit of using my left thumb to hit Command so I could let my RSI heal. Karabiner let me disable the key. +1.

Comment: The "Application" Key between the right Fn and right ctrl was inserting invisible invalid characters into my code(when pressed accidentally) and making the compilation to fail. This helped me in mapping it to right-command key to avoid this issue. Thanks a ton for this answer and this software is just amazing. This is exactly what I have been looking for a few months as I have starting using Mac after years of using a Windows PC.

Comment: My right and bottom arrow keys are stuck. Disabled those keys successfully using Karabiner. Thank you so much for this!